# Single lettered function names in jquery/json?

Tags: json, function, jquery

Can someone please explain what this code does. 
The thing that I found most irritating about this function is its single-lettered name. How can i know what is the purpose of this function and what invokes this funciton.

```
    function i() {
        $(".main_section").delegate(".saveExam", "click", function () {
            ename = $("#addmore").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "saveNewExam.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    examId: ename
                },
                dataType: "html",
                success: function (e) {}
            });
            window.location.reload()
        })
    }
```

Comment: why would the name matter in this case? the code tells you what it does. If there are any function calls in this code that you don't know, google them, and you should be able to find out what this does in a few minutes.

Comment: Longer names are not necessarily better. Would it be more understandable if it were `function blahblahblah()`?

Comment: Yes, if it did some 'blah blah blah'-ing.

Comment: You would more easily know what the function did in the various places in which it was called rather than having to go to the function declaration to figure it out.  comments would be nice, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes a POST request to `saveNewExam.php` with the `examId` that is picked up from the element with an id of `addmore`. Immediately after making the POST request, before waiting for a response, it refreshes the page.

Answer (score 0):

This is a function definition, so it's explaining to you right here what the function does.  It's meant to be used later somewhere else in the code.  This particular function fires an ajax request when a `".saveExam"` element is clicked.

Comment: Please also tell the use of:
1. delegate() function on line 2 &
2. success: function(e){} on line 11